# Wrong version of the zip extension displayed in php.ini vs pecl install

Tags: php, homebrew, pecl

when I'm issuing the composer update command, I get an error :

```
[18:54] thomas@Thomass-MBP:~/Dropbox/eclipse-workspace/crf2/RedCrossQuest/server$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested PHP extension ext-zip ^7.2 has the wrong version (1.15.4) installed. Install or enable PHP's zip extension.
```

1.15.4 is indeed the version reported when doing a phpinfo();

To fix that, I've tried to update zip by using PECL.
The first time I ran the command, I saw some standard compilation messages (but I think there was some warning)

I've restarted apache and it's still showing the 1.15.4 version.
And composer is also still complaining about the 1.15.4 version.

In addition, I started to have warning about the zip extension included twice.
PHP Warning:  Module 'zip' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

I had to remove the extension from the php.ini, but I don't understand from where it's now included.

When I try to install again, I get this :

```
[18:43] thomas@Thomass-MBP:~$ sudo pecl install zip
Password:
pecl/zip is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.15.5
install failed
```

I've uninstalled all extension and  reinstalled them, and now :

```
sudo pecl   install grpc protobuf xdebug zip
sudo pecl uninstall grpc protobuf xdebug zip
```

```
[19:30] thomas@Thomass-MBP:/usr/local/etc/php/7.2$ php
/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.2/7.2.22_1/pecl/20170718/protobuf.so doesn't appear to be a valid Zend extension
/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.2/7.2.22_1/pecl/20170718/grpc.so doesn't appear to be a valid Zend extension
PHP Warning:  Module 'zip' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Module 'zip' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Xdebug MUST be loaded as a Zend extension in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Xdebug MUST be loaded as a Zend extension in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'xdebug' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Module 'xdebug' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

I think brew just blew up my php installation... :(

Any idea how to clean up this mess?

Comment: How did you access phpinfo? Via the web or via the command line? php command line sometimes is configured to have a different php.ini. Maybe that's it? What's the output of 'php -i'

Comment: php -i and phpinfo() give the same php.ini file location 

Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/etc/php/7.2
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/etc/php/7.2/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /usr/local/etc/php/7.2/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed => /usr/local/etc/php/7.2/conf.d/ext-opcache.ini

Comment: Are there multiple ini file in php.d directory that are loading the module multiple times?

Comment: Nope, I've checked that as well. It's weird. I'll try to remove and reinstall httpd/php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the brew formula comes with zip extension built-in in version 1.15.4, as I've just reinstalled httpd/php and zip is already present.

it's unlikely that PECL can override this.

There's either an issue in brew or in composer.
My guess is that it's a composer issue : 
https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/8342

A work around provided by xabbuh on the github ticket is to put a wild card instead of the version.

so :

```
"ext-zip" : "*"
```

instead of

```
"ext-zip" : "^7.2"
```

about the

```
/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.2/7.2.22_1/pecl/20170718/protobuf.so doesn't appear to be a valid Zend extension
/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.2/7.2.22_1/pecl/20170718/grpc.so doesn't appear to be a valid Zend extension
```

It seems that pecl incorrectly add the extension as zend_extension (while it also add them as "extension" and sometime two time for one extension)...